# How to retroactively remove the shiny effect of graphite pencils?

Tags: sketching, pencil-shading, graphite

I made a sketch using graphite and charcoal pencils in low-light. When I looked at the sketch under *normal* lighting, it was very shiny.

How can I retroactively make a graphite sketch less shiny?
[image]